# VS code not giving npm package method recommendation

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

hy, i am beginner in node.js and npm
i have download npm package but "VS code not giving me downloaded npm package method name recommendation"
which will be very helpful for me in future

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio code relies on TypeScript type declaration (typings) files for its IntelliSense feature:

> VS Code uses TypeScript type declaration (typings) files (for example `node.d.ts`) to provide metadata to VS Code about the JavaScript based frameworks you are consuming in your application.

<sup>[Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial)</sup>

While it's [been](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/pull/247) [requested](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/issues/789) [many](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/issues/662) [times](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/issues/1194), it doesn't appear that the `validator` library includes any TypeScript type declaration files as of this writing.